# how to order custom post based on meta keys in wordpress admin

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post named 'Product' with meta key as 'Prioritized'. I have many drafts added to the post. Now, in admin I want to sort the posts so the product list comes as per the user.
I have tried many plugins but none is met for my requirements. I want to sort those posts only which are published and checked as prioritized.
Is this possible?
Any help/suggestions are welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'your-post-type',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_status'    => array('publish'),   
    'meta_key'       => 'your key name',//prioritized
    'meta_value'     => 'your key value'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        the_title();
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: This would be a way of doing this on the front end of the site, my understanding of the question is with regards to the admin area though.

Answer (score 0):

You can display author and custom fields columns by [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/). I'm not sure can you sort rows by this fields or not.